# Duplicate Key error for Select/Option but I'm using UUID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For my Select/Option I want to map my  data to several options. Pretty straight forward. However, I noticed I keep on getting a " Encountered two children with the same key, `.$1#1`."

I am fairly certain my key is UUID, so this should never happen right? I've isolate the error to this block of code:

```
<Select 
    defaultValue={this.props.data[0].unit_quantity+" 
    "+this.props.data[0].unit_of_measurement} 
    style={{ width: 120, marginLeft: "-15vw", marginRight: "2vw"}} 
    onChange = {this.changePrice}>   
       {this.props.data.map((i) => 
          <Option 
              value={i.price+"#"+i.amount_in_stock}
              key = {i.id}> 
              {i.unit_quantity+" "+i.unit_of_measurement} 
          </Option>
       )}
</Select>
```

I notice the key errors happen for the items with matching item.price, and when I changed those, I have no more key errors. However, don't I clearly have it here my `{key = {i.id}`?
Thanks

Comment: Whenever you are facing the issue, did you try verifying what IDs you are getting?

Comment: I did. I can confirm the item.id are different and this only occurs when the values are the same.

Comment: Just as a sanity check try using map( (I, k) =>... key={k}...) which will then use the item’s index within map as the key rather than a value from the data.

Comment: Key is something that should be unique for sure. If you are getting same value in some case or the other you cant use that value as key. See if you got something else to use as key.

Comment: From the react docs (note: uniqueness is amongst siblings): The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys
...
When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort.

Comment: Sorry I might've been vague with the words. When I print out the item.id, They are always different (its uuid4) When I refer to value, I refer to {i.price+"#"+i.amount_in_stock}. I notice the error only occurs when an item has the same price and stock as another item. I'm starting to suspect this is an Ant-d specific error.